# Mule Expression Language: Access value in an array?

Tags: arrays, mule, mule-studio

I set a breakpoint and captured this array.

[image]

How do I programmatically access the key and value for a given element in the array?  I've tried a few different things including the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried message.inboundAttachments.get(1)?

Comment: Just did, that doesn't work either.  Null

Comment: I'd try get(key), so get("test.xml")

Comment: But I don't know what the attachments will be named... ?

Comment: I know, but just to check. That looks like a map and if that is the case you need to go through it in a different manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `inboundAttachments` is a map so you can only access a specific value using it's key, not an index. Of course you can also get a collection of all keys or values.